# Memory issue while building spark

Tags: java, scala, sbt, apache-spark

I have installed Scala, sbt and hadoop 1.0.3 over Ubuntu 12.o4 client OS. With the reference of link - http://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/How_to_Install_Spark_on_Ubuntu-12.04, I tried building Spark and got error related to reserve space.

Here is what I am trying to run:

```
hduser@vignesh-desktop:/usr/local/spark-1.1.0$ SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=1.1.0 sbt/sbt assembly
```

Output with following error:

```
Using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/ as default JAVA_HOME.
Note, this will be overridden by -java-home if it is set.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get this solved by passing mem attribute with sbt command as given below, (for 4 GB RAM system)

```
SPARK_HADOOP_VERSION=1.1.0 sbt/sbt assembly -mem 1024
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the exact command you passed in the terminal?

Comment: You can pass size of available RAM after -mem parameter.  (This is the exact command)